# Button get disappeared in IE 9 while using disabled prop

Tags: html

```
<button type="button" id="update">Submit</button>
<button type="button" id="updated">Update</button>

 $("#updated").click(function(){
     $("#update").prop('disabled',true);
 })
```

Hi,

I want disabled button,when I am using above It works fine for all browser,except some versions of IE like IE 9,In IE 9 button get disappeared when I am using above code.

can anybody say me why this happen.

Thanks,
Nandkishor